# Stack Overflow does not use Captcha for verification anymore, how can they defend against bots?

Tags: discussion, captcha, robots

Last time I posted a question (about one year ago), I noticed that Stack Overflow had the "Are you human?" verification check with Captcha. Now, we seem to be able to just post questions and answers freely (as I noticed today).

How can you prevent against bots, then?

Comment: It isn't disabled. I got it a few days ago when posting a few answers in quick succession.

Comment: @Oded: But relaxed, maybe?

Comment: Yes - it certainly isn't as... eager as it has been in the past.

Comment: I still see the verification whenever I am using a mobile device; switching IP addresses is a trigger.

Comment: Yup, I got one just today...

Comment: @JonSkeet: It dared to question Jon Skeet... we live in a dark world.

Comment: A mod and Jon Skeet confirm being Captcha'd recently: perhaps someone should look into the possibility that the Captcha are in open revolt against important people?

Comment: I get a Captcha when I type much too fast for a human being. Often I type like a human who's reasonably fast but pausing to think and it accepts that as evidence that I _am_ human. I find if I slow down and make some mistakes towards the end of writing an answer, it'll forgive me for any near light-speed typing earlier on.

Comment: I never get CAPTCHA'ed. Does that mean I am human or just   a smart bot?

Comment: @Magoo111: RIP StackOverflow, killed in the 2013 CAPTCHA uprising.

Answer (score 1):

The captcha appears when huge amounts of text are pasted in a post body at once.

There are other things that trigger the CAPTCHA, and I will add them as I find them out.

Comment: There are other things that trigger it. *Bot-like* things. Be very suspicious of anyone who complains about CAPTCHAs, lest they rend you asunder with their cold metal hands.

Comment: @Shog9 Brilliantly put :)